# Is this async or blocking code?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Is this blocking code if I have `JSON.stringify` inside `writeFile`.Lets say it is big file. Is this why I am getting error `conection refused` when I push button multiple times in second which triggers this api endpoint?

```
 app.patch('/', function(req, res) {
...some query
fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, "../../") + 'Data/deals.json', JSON.stringify(tickets), function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(400).json({error: err});
        }
        return res.status(200).json({success: true, message: 'Deal Updated successfully'});
    });
})
```

Comment: Maybe because the write action isn't completed yet, so the document is locked in the filesystem (the same would happen if you open a text file in windows and try to rename it at the same time)

Comment: I get `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` if I do GET in <1000ms for the same resorce...

Comment: Define "big file". `JSON.stringify()` is pretty fast. Also, getting a "connection refused" is not a symptom of something blocking the event loop (that would cause requests to hang).

Comment: @robertklep you are right, nodemon was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit #1:

`JSON.stringify` parsing object to string **synchronously**. but you missing that you called `JSON.stringify` inside the `patch` function and not inside the writeFIle.

#### Original:

It's `Async`. if you want to write a file synchronously you have to use `writeFileSync`.

For more information visit [**Node.js fs Docs**](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

#### Example

```
// Async callback will called after finish
// Non-Blocking
fs.writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)

// write to file with return the result, may throw exception    
// Blocking
fs.writeFileSync(file, data[, options])
```

Comment: No, it is blocking code... When I do patch, and imidiatelly after that < 1000ms, I do GET for the same resource... I get `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`... I think that is because JSON.stringify is V8 code - pure JS blocking code... it does not run on event loop...maybe...

Comment: Yes, tnx, nodemon was a problem